# How can I remove space between two columns of square containers?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[ref image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSkbT.png)

I have two columns of blocks, and I need to do space between all of them the same.

Please help

Here a code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="./img/02.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-primary"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-secondary"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-success"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-danger"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

There is Css that I also have:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}

p {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.square-container {
    width: 220px;
    height: 235px;
}

.grid-gap {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

I tried to do it with grid. But with grid all squares goes down in one column

Comment: what do you mean by `space between all of them the same` ? can you share current and expected reference ?

Comment: so, on the image you can see one big space between two columns. I want to reduce it and make same space between blocks in each columns

Comment: can you also add your css to the question what you already have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap `col-md-6` class has `50%` width and paddling left and right of `15px`

To remove extra space between the columns, first make `.square-container`'s width to `100%` so there won't be extra space inside column.

If you need more or less space than default `15px`, then you can manually override this or you can use gutter for spacing between columns.

[bootstrap gutters docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/6kpvx29e/14/)

Comment: Simply use gutters for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `display: grid` and define the columns and the `gap` property.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using boostrap **row** class, so just use **g** class for gap. And it will work. Here is a sample code:

```
       <div class="row gx-4 gy-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="./img/02.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-primary"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-secondary"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-success"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="square-container bg-danger"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I used **gx** for horizontal spacing and **gy** for vertical spacing. You can use simple **g** for both horizontal and vertical spacing.